# Exporting data set from Google Earth Engine for use in Google Earth

Tags: google-earth, google-earth-engine

So I have a date range of MODIS temperature images that I am attempting to export from GEE for use in Google Earth. This is what the code looks like thus far:

```js
var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/006/MYD11A2')
                  .filter(ee.Filter.date('2018-05-01', '2018-06-01'));
var landSurfaceTemperature = dataset.select('LST_Day_1km');
var landSurfaceTemperatureVis = {
  min: 14000.0,
  max: 16000.0,
  palette: [
    '040274', '040281', '0502a3', '0502b8', '0502ce', '0502e6',
    '0602ff', '235cb1', '307ef3', '269db1', '30c8e2', '32d3ef',
    '3be285', '3ff38f', '86e26f', '3ae237', 'b5e22e', 'd6e21f',
    'fff705', 'ffd611', 'ffb613', 'ff8b13', 'ff6e08', 'ff500d',
    'ff0000', 'de0101', 'c21301', 'a71001', '911003'
  ],
};
Map.setCenter(-85.60371794450282,44.73590436363271, 8);
Map.addLayer(
    landSurfaceTemperature, landSurfaceTemperatureVis,
    'Land Surface Temperature');

// Create a geometry representing an export region.
var features = ee.Geometry.Rectangle([-85.1417893413635, 45.31413490213395, -86.125065708551, 44.65070625463291]);
```

Where I am having trouble is coding the export feature that would allow for an overlay to be placed into Google Earth. This is what I have now:

```js
// Export the image, specifying scale and region.
Export.image.toDrive({
  image: dataset.filter('LST_Day_1km'),
  description: 'Overlay',
  scale: 30,
  region: features
});
```

So what do I need to add to that code to facilitate the export of the color-coded data set into a .kmz, GeoTIFF or some sort of file that could be overlayed in Google Earth? Do I need to .sum() the image set prior to export?

This is for personal use, so I do not need to embed it into a website, so I don't think I will need to use the API provided by Earth Engine....or do it?

Answer (score 0):

The `Export.image` already exports in GeoTIFF format, that's the default for `fileFormat` argument. Your real issue is that your code won't work in this form. `dataset` is a collection with multiple bands, while export works with type `Image`. You'd need to e.g. select specific band and image. The latter can be e.g. first item in the collection or some sort of aggregation - up to you.

Here's an example:

```
Export.image.toDrive({
  image: dataset.select('LST_Day_1km').first(),
  description: 'Overlay',
  scale: 30,
  region: features,
  fileFormat: 'GeoTIFF'
});
```